# Proving logarithmic inequality

Tags: inequality, logarithms, induction

I was looking through my old notebook from uni and I stumbled upon this exercise. Sadly I couldn’t solve it then I cannot do it now. What would be best approach with this question?
For $a>2$ and $n>0$, prove using induction that $\log_a(1+n)<n$. I’m not sure why $a$ has to be larger than 2. I’ve plotted both sides of inequality and graphically makes sense. I’ve tried to raise both sides to the power of $a$, but that’s as far I could get with it.

Comment: You need $a>2$ because $\log_2(1+1)=1 \not < 1$

Comment: Try to prove  $1+n < a^n$

Answer (score 0):

$$a>2 \implies \log_a2<1$$
This means that for $n=1$, $\log_a(1+1)<2$.

For $n=k$, $$\log_a(1+k)<k \implies a^k>1+k \implies a^{k+1}>a(1+k)>2(1+k)>2+k $$
$$\implies \log_a(2+k)<k+1$$
Hence, proved by induction.